# Syntax error when passing named arguments with ":" to function

Tags: python, syntax-error

I am trying to download economic information from the Central Bank of Ecuador with the package "getBCE" from https://github.com/Danjar27/BCE. I tried to reproduce the GitHub example:

```
from getBCE.menu import *

balanza_de_pagos = getBCE(
    year: '2021',
    month: 'junio',
    indicator: '063',
)
```

But I get this error:

```
Input In [1]
    year: '2021',
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Why do they give this example if it is a syntax error? Does this code make sense in any context I'm not aware of?

Comment: Yes, I know. Your question makes this clear.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
balanza_de_pagos = getBCE(
    year='2021',
    month='junio',
    indicator='063',
)
```

Since *year, month, indicator* are the [arguments](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-argument) to the getBCE function.

Answer (score 0):

I have looked at the source of getBCE and I have found this:

```
class getBCE:

    def __init__(self, year: str, month: str, index: str, **opciones):
```

This means that this should work:

```
balanza_de_pagos = getBCE(
    year='2021',
    month='junio',
    index='063',
)
```

But, it doesn't work for me, I get some other error. I hope it might work for you.

Comment: @SilvioGuerra Copy just the second snippet of code I posted. It is actually the same as the other answer with the difference that "index" is the name of third parameter instead of "indicator". But I am getting an error "ssl.SSLError: [SSL: DH_KEY_TOO_SMALL] dh key too small" which is probably a bug in the getBCE library..

Comment: I also get a SSLError, it may be a bug in the getBCE. Thank you anyway.